# How to access Arista switch login?

Tags: command-line-interface, switch, putty, serial

I have an Arista 7048T-A switch that needs to be set up. However I can't seem to access the login prompt for the switch. I'm using PuTTY over serial connection. What i mean by not being able to access the switch login is that when the CLI boots up I get prompted to log into localhost. After following the quick-start manual to avail I'm still stuck. I can only log into `localhost>` but not `switch>`. I've even reset the switch from Aboot, no difference. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the text before the prompt is just whatever the device host name is, in a lot of switch documentation they choose the host name 'switch'.  So I wouldn't worry too much that yours (I'm guessing) says localhost> and the documentation says switch>

The varying degrees of access are denoted by the prompt character or the bracketed section of the prompt.  In Cisco IOS land (and that of the CLIs similar to it, e.g. most of them) the hash denotes that you're logged into an 'privileged enable mode' session and when in 'configuration mode' you get the (config) added.

Here's what I've found from their documentation:

> Admin Username
>
> The initial configuration provides one username, admin,
>   that is not assigned a password. When using the admin username without
>   a password, you can only log into the switch through the console port.
>   After a password is assigned to the admin username, it can log into
>   the switch through any port. The username command assigns a password
>   to the specified username. 
>   Example • This command assigns the password
>   pxq123 to the admin username:
>
> switch(config)#username admin secret pxq123
>
> switch(config)#

In reading further down here're the exact steps Arista suggest you take to make your initial console login, before the 'admin' user has a password:

> localhost login: admin
>
> admin
>
> localhost>

So after you get to that prompt you need to enter config/enable mode (command 'en' will get you to privileged enable mode, then 'config' to enter Global Configuration mode) and take your setup steps, e.g. setting up users, passwords, access levels, host names, all that good stuff.

https://www.arista.com/assets/data/docs/Manuals/EOS-4.17.0F-Manual.pdf

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. This really cleared things up since the manual didn't specify it was just a name or how it changed between steps. I also have a follow up question. I don;t know if I should create a separate question. After enabling privileged mode (following the manual for initial setup), the command 'localhost#interface management 0' returns Invalid input.

Comment: So you've got to be in 'Global Configuration Mode' before you can enter 'Interface Configuration Mode'.  I don't spot the (config) text in what you've just said but perhaps you're paraphrasing.  In any case please have a good read of the manual and note the below section:

Comment: Navigating Through Command ModesTo change the active command mode, perform one of these actions:
•To enter EXEC mode, log into the switch.
•To enter Privileged EXEC mode from EXEC, type enable (or en) followed, if prompted, by the enable password:switch>enPassword:switch#
•To enter Global Configuration mode from Privileged EXEC, type configure (or config):switch#configswitch(config)# 
•To enter Interface Configuration mode from Global Configuration, type interface and the name of the interface to be modified:switch(config)#interface Et24switch(config-if-Et24)#